# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'styles') + Using withLess/withSass/withCSS in next.config.js NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, antd

I am trying to configure a NextJS 12 project with custom Ant Design and according to some examples that I have found, I must configure my `next.config.js` file with the libraries `@zeit/next-sass` / `@zeit/next-less` / `@zeit/next-css` but when I doing I get the following error in console:

```
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'styles')
    at module.exports (/Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/@zeit/next-css/css-loader-config.js:25:56)
    at Object.webpack (/Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/@zeit/next-css/index.js:15:36)
    at Object.getBaseWebpackConfig [as default] (/Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack-config.js:1364:32)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
    at async HotReloader.start (/Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader.js:321:25)
    at async DevServer.prepare (/Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:289:9)
    at async /Users/overmartinez/Projects/OMA/omawarehouse/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:126:9
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have tried in many ways but none of them work for me, just by adding the use of the library without any other configuration I get the error,

This is the recommended configuration of `next.config.js`

```
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
const lessToJS = require('less-vars-to-js')
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')

const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

// Where your antd-custom.less file lives
const themeVariables = lessToJS(
    fs.readFileSync(
        path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/themes/default.less'),
        'utf8',
    ),
)

const plugins = [
    [
        withLess({
            lessLoaderOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                modifyVars: themeVariables, // make your antd custom effective
            },
            webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
                if (isServer) {
                    const antStyles = /antd\/.*?\/style.*?/
                    const origExternals = [...config.externals]
                    config.externals = [
                        (context, request, callback) => {
                            if (request.match(antStyles)) return callback()
                            if (typeof origExternals[0] === 'function') {
                                origExternals[0](context, request, callback)
                            } else {
                                callback()
                            }
                        },
                        ...(typeof origExternals[0] === 'function'
                            ? []
                            : origExternals),
                    ]

                    config.module.rules.unshift({
                        test: antStyles,
                        use: 'null-loader',
                    })
                }

                const builtInLoader = config.module.rules.find(rule => {
                    if (rule.oneOf) {
                        return (
                            rule.oneOf.find(deepRule => {
                                return (
                                    deepRule.test &&
                                    deepRule.test.toString().includes('/a^/')
                                )
                            }) !== undefined
                        )
                    }
                    return false
                })

                if (typeof builtInLoader !== 'undefined') {
                    config.module.rules.push({
                        oneOf: [
                            ...builtInLoader.oneOf.filter(rule => {
                                return (
                                    (rule.test &&
                                        rule.test
                                            .toString()
                                            .includes('/a^/')) !== true
                                )
                            }),
                        ],
                    })
                }

                config.resolve.alias['@'] = path.resolve(__dirname)
                return config
            },
        }),
    ],
]

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, nextConfig)
```

But even with this minimal config it fail

```
const withLess = require('@zeit/next-less')
const lessToJS = require('less-vars-to-js')
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')

const plugins = [[withLess()]]

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, nextConfig)
```

My scaffold
[image]

Only works without plugins

```
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')

const nextConfig = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = withPlugins([], nextConfig)
```

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

What am I doing wrong? If someone can help me I would be so thankful.

Comment: Have you tried to use this package for less? I had used it in Next.js 12 and is working fine. [next-with-less](https://github.com/elado/next-with-less)

Comment: I'd also recommend [`next-plugin-antd-less`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-plugin-antd-less) which is specifically tailored for Antd.

Comment: Yes, you all right!  next-with-less package works fine for me! thanks @MusawerShah

Comment: And I will take a look to this one too! thanks @juliomalves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new versions of Next.js (>=12) you can put the imports of your `*.scss/*.less` files directly in the `_app.js` file, so! you don't need to do anything special in your `next.config.js` file to handle this specific case.

In my case, I was able to solve it with this:

#### My `next.config.js`

```js
const withLess = require('next-with-less')
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins')
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')

const plugins = [[withLess, {}], [nextTranslate]]

module.exports = withPlugins(plugins, {
    reactStrictMode: true,
    swcMinify: true, // <- To enable SWC compiler
    images: {
        domains: ['i2.wp.com'], // <- To allow use images from this domain
    },
})
```

#### My `_app.js`

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css'

import App from 'next/app'
import { wrapper } from '~/redux/store'
import { AppContextProvider } from '~/context/index'
import(`~/assets/less/themes/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SKIN}-antd.less`) // <- antd theme

class MyApp extends App {
    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

        return (
            <AppContextProvider>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </AppContextProvider>
        )
    }
}

export default wrapper.withRedux(MyApp)
```

#### My scafolding

[image]

#### Default Ant Design less variables

[antd less variables](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/style/themes/default.less)

#### My `tcp-antd.less` theme file

```less
@import '~antd/lib/style/themes/default.less';
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
@import './tcp.less'; // <- Replace the antd's default styles
@import './custom.less';
```